# Where to find GDP for sub-sectors of a Nation?

Tags: gdp

I was recently doing a presentation for Economics Class in which I wanted to break down the GDP of the UAE by Emirate. I could not find anything on the internet about this, although a quick google search reveals GDP contributions for each state last year in the U.S. to the overall national GDP. Is this information publicly available? If so, what are some good sources that break down countries' GDP into regional contributions?

Comment: [List of country subdivisions by GDP over 200 billion USD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_subdivisions_by_GDP_over_200_billion_USD) lists multiple sources. This is not a single aggregated source, so I do not add this as an answer.

Comment: Most countries have this statistics done by the authority that compiles the national statistics (GDP) although the number might be lagged by a year or two. I couldn't find one for UAE though.